# Rails send_data creating blank file from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to download a file filled with a string. However, no matter which way I try, the file ends up blank.

Here is the relevant code:

```
  def export(notes)
    stream = render_to_string(:template=>"cards/export.enex.erb", :locals => {:notes => notes}, :formats => [:enex])
    send_data(stream.to_s, :filename => "notes.enex")
  end
```

I have been using Rails.logger.info to try to track down the problem and have confirmed that stream is not empty and (when prompted to) my log shows that the file was sent full of the correct data. I am using a custom mime type (enex) and that is all set up correctly in config. I've tried several different methods and nothing works. Here are some other attempts:

(1)

```
  @notes = notes
  render file: "cards/export", formats: [:enex], type: 'text/plain', disposition: 'attatchment; filename=cards.enex'
```

(2)

```
  render template: "cards/export", formats: [:enex], :locals => {:notes => notes}, type: 'text/plain', disposition: "attatchment", filename: "notes.enex"
```

(3)

```
  send_file 'app/views/cards/export.enex.erb', type: 'application/enex', disposition: "attachment; filename=notecards.enex", :x_sendfile=>true
```

In each case, the file ends up blank.

As you can see, the string I am using is created by filling out an erb form. If it matters, "notes" is a hash that I use to fill out the form. I know how to get this to work by using a button on a view and a respond_to in the controller but I am purposely not using the database and would prefer to solve the problem using a private controller method as shown.

I am using Rails 4

Can you see anything that would cause the send_data to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using send_file but instead of giving it the path to the erb, give it the path to the file you generated with that template and specify the type as application/xml or text/xml. I don't have experience with enex files, but I think this may simplify the issue.

```
file = "my_file.enex"
File.open(file, "w") do |f| 
   f << render_to_string(:template=>"cards/export.enex.erb", :locals => {:notes => notes}, :formats => [:enex]) 
end
send_file(file.path, type: "application/xml")
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I gave it a try and it does download the file, but it's still empty.

Comment: Interesting... Does  'my_file.enex' file in your server's file system have content in it?

Comment: Your's fixed it. Thanks!